# How to optimize Sieve of Eratosthenes to reduce repeated marking of composites

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a popular algorithm to find prime numbers up to a given limit. It is very simple and I find it very suitable to implement in a programming language as way to improve my skills.

But it is also extremely inefficient.

The basic version goes like this:

Start with a list of all integers from 0 to n, **mark** 0 and 1 not prime. Then, go through all numbers from 2 to n, if it is not **marked** as composite, then the number is a prime number p, **mark** all multiples kp of p as composite, k starts at 2 and increments by 1 each subsequent iteration, until kp > n. The resultant list of integers that aren't **marked** as composite is all primes up to n.

The algorithm performs lots of extra work. It **checks** way too many numbers and repeatedly **marks** same numbers composite.

Starting at 7, all prime numbers modulo 30 must be one of the following: $\{7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 1\}$, the differences between consecutive terms are $(4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6)$, the necessary **checks** of primes becomes $\frac{4}{15}$ of the original.
The number of **checks** can be further improved by only considering numbers up to $\sqrt{n}$, because composite numbers no greater than n will be **marked** by being a multiple of a prime number no greater than $\sqrt{n}$. The number of **checks** would therefore be $\frac{4\sqrt{n}}{15}$.

But the bulk of calculation is done in the **marking** of composites, most composites are **marked** repeatedly, the work is redundant and decrease the number of times the same composite number is **marked** can increase performance.

But I only managed to do two obvious improvements here.

The original algorithm **marks** $floor(\frac{n - 2p} {p})$ numbers composite for each prime number p.

By **marking** only odd multiples of p composite (given $p \ne 2$), this would decrease the number of **marks** to $floor(\frac{n - 2p} {2p}) + 1$. Start the **marking** at the square of the prime, multiples less than square would already have been marked. This decreases number of **marks** to $floor(\frac{n - p ^ 2}{2p}) + 1$.

The following is the Python implementation of the algorithm I just described:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle

def prime_wheel_sieve(n: int) -> np.ndarray:
    wheel = cycle([4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6])
    primes = np.ones(n + 1, dtype=bool)
    primes[:2] = False
    for square, step in ((4, 2), (9, 6), (25, 10)):
        primes[square::step] = False

    k = 7
    while (square := k * k) <= n:
        if primes[k]:
            primes[square :: 2 * k] = False

        k += next(wheel)
    return np.where(primes)[0]
```

With slight modification I can use it to count the number of checks, strikes and such:

```
def analyze_prime_wheel_sieve(n: int) -> tuple:
    n += 1
    wheel = cycle([4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6])
    primes = np.ones(n, dtype=bool)
    primes[:2] = False
    marks = 0
    for square, step in ((4, 2), (9, 6), (25, 10)):
        primes[square::step] = False
        marks += (n - square) // step + 1

    hit = 3
    count = 3
    k = 7
    while (square := k * k) <= n:
        if primes[k]:
            primes[square :: (step := 2 * k)] = False
            marks += (n - square) // step + 1
            hit += 1

        k += next(wheel)
        count += 1
    
    composites = n - np.sum(primes)
    return (count, hit, count - hit, marks, composites, marks / composites)
```

The first value in the tuple is the count of total number of primality checking, the second value is the total number of times the checked value is a prime, the third is the number of times when it is a composite.

The fourth means the total number of times the program had marked a number composite, the fifth is the count of all unique composite numbers marked, and the sixth the ratio of number of times composites are marked over count of unique composites.

I have investigated the number of primes up to $\{2^n | n \in [2, 25] \cap \mathbb{Z}\}$:

```
In [78]: for i in range(8, 26):
    ...:     print(analyze_prime_wheel_sieve(1 << i))
(6, 6, 0, 219, 203, 1.0788177339901477)
(8, 8, 0, 467, 416, 1.1225961538461537)
(11, 11, 0, 984, 853, 1.153575615474795)
(14, 14, 0, 2059, 1740, 1.1833333333333333)
(19, 18, 1, 4296, 3533, 1.215963770166997)
(26, 24, 2, 8919, 7165, 1.24480111653873)
(36, 31, 5, 18471, 14485, 1.2751812219537453)
(51, 42, 9, 38090, 29257, 1.3019106538606147)
(70, 54, 16, 78372, 58995, 1.3284515636918384)
(99, 72, 27, 160895, 118822, 1.3540842604904815)
(139, 97, 42, 329653, 239145, 1.3784649480440736)
(195, 128, 67, 674170, 480899, 1.4018952004474952)
(275, 172, 103, 1376629, 966552, 1.424267913159354)
(388, 229, 159, 2807364, 1941542, 1.4459455422545584)
(548, 309, 239, 5717981, 3898358, 1.4667665206735758)
(774, 418, 356, 11632646, 7824446, 1.4867053846368166)
(1094, 564, 530, 23641614, 15699346, 1.5058980163887081)
(1547, 760, 787, 48004793, 31490744, 1.5244096169972994)
```

I have found that for bigger limits, more and more prime checks are misses, and it seems that more and more composites are marked repeatedly.

The first problem can be solved by using a bigger wheel, but the second problem is harder to solve. I don't know if the ratio of all markings over unique composites converges to something or diverges to infinity, I conjecture it to go off to infinity albeit at a decreasing rate.

I want to decrease the number of marks per composite number (the last element in the tuples), to make the ratio closer to 1. How can I do that? I have tried to do it, but the results were wrong, and there is already a wall of text. See the edit [history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4757923/revisions) for more details.

Comment: "extremely inefficient" - not really , although there are improvements.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what exactly you are asking about. But I think you may be interested in sieve of Atkin (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) - it has better asymptotic complexity. However, on practice even simple Eratosphenes sieve on odd numbers up to square root is enough for $N$ up to tens of millions at least (and there are optimisations of it to make it more cache-friendly and reduce memory requirements, which are even harder to outperform).

Comment: You might get a kick out of the [primes drag race project](https://github.com/PlummersSoftwareLLC/Primes) initiated by Dave Plummer.

Comment: A web search for 'optimize sieve of eratosthenes' turns up a bunch of promising results.